# Haskellのレコード構文をScalaで書きたい

Tags: scala, haskell

Haskellにレコード構文というものがあります。
(以下のコードはすごいHaskell楽しく学ぼうのP119からの引用です)

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String
, lastName :: String
, age :: Int
, height :: Float
, phoneNumber :: String
, flavor :: String } deriving (Show)
```

こちらをScalaで書こうとするとこのようになるのでしょうか。

```
case class Person(
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  age: Int,
  height: Float,
  phoneNumber: String,
  flavor: String
)
```

Scalaですと一般的なクラス定義がHaskellのレコード構文と同じような感じになりますが、いかがなものでしょうか。

ご教示のほど、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 自分の感覚としては一般的にはcase classで対応させるのが普通で、そういう意味では既に答えが出てる気もします。

が「一般的にcase classでやる」という答えが欲しいのか、HaskellのレコードでしかできそうにないことをScalaでどうやるのか？を知りたいのか、
case classとHaskellのレコードの詳細な違いが知りたい？のか、case classでやる方法は知ってるけど、それ以外でどいういう方法があるのか知りたい？、など、もう少し質問が具体的でもいい気がしました

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問の仕方が悪かったです。case classで実装してみましたが、これでよいのか自信がなかったので質問させていただいた次第であります。

Comment: @shigemk2  これで良いと思いますよ～。